# Extending a closed DLL - by merging?

Tags: c#, dll, merge, extend

I am currently faced with a problem of extending a library (dll) which is which is closed to the eventual user.
The library has a class:

```
 public partial Extender
 {
     ...
 }
```

which is nominally where the extension is intended to happen, but of course the eventual user cannot directly 
replace this class with their own.
To test out an approach I have built a solution with 3 projects:

MainLibrary - a class library project, containing the code that is nominally closed to the eventual user. Contains:

```
    public partial Extender
    {
        ...
    }
```

code in this library instantiates and uses the Extender class which is to all intents and purposes empty.
ExtenderLibrary - a class library project, referencing MainLibrary, and containing:

```
    public partial Extender
    {
        ...
        //  contains methods that the eventual user wants to invoke
        ...
    }
```

I want this class to become the 'concrete implementation' of MainLibrary:Extender and operate just as if it was the 'original' class.

ConsoleApp - a console app which references MainLibrary and is intended to be the driver to
                 validate that I can call the methods in Extender

My current approach is based on the [blog of Scott Hanselmann](http://www.hanselmann.com.blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx)
, although in my case I dont have a mixed language scenario, basically trying to merge MainLibrary and ExtenderLibrary so 
that the single merged form (of Extender via its partial kwd) 
can be then addressed by the ConsolApp.
I have had no success in getting this merging approach to work.

Does anyone have some insights as to how I can achieve what I want here?

Comment: So you want to distribute `ExtenderLibrary` for other people to develop with, without needing to include `MainLibrary`?  Because end users won't see any of this.

Comment: You do realize `partial` is only a keyword the c# compiler does understand? In the compiled dll the concept of partial is no longer visible. *The partial keyword indicates that other parts of the class, struct, or interface can be defined in the namespace. All the parts must use the partial keyword. All the parts must be available at compile time to form the final type.* from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx